# How do I start and stop a systemctl service inside a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, systemd, services

I am writing a bash script to perform a daily backup. This script will ultimately run automatically every morning (cron or systemd).

What I would like to accomplish is

1. Stop myservice
2. Perform backup procedures
3. Start myservice

The bash script I have created looks something like this:

```
# Stop myservice
systemctl stop myservice.service

# Do all the backing up here...

# Start myservice
systemctl start myservice.service
```

The issue I am having is that when I run this script, it requires my password during the systemctl stop/start calls. If this is to run automatically, obviously it can't require a password every time. How do I run this script automatically without requiring this password?

Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities, depending on your needs and preferences.

### An apparent approach …

… would be to run the whole script as user `root` by adding it to `root`'s `crontab` (using `sudo crontab -e`). It won't need any password then when `systemctl stop/start myservice.service` is run. The downside is that you may need to run the backup tasks as another user (say `noslenkwah`) and have to switch to that other user for the backup. Example:

```
# Stop myservice
systemctl stop myservice.service

# Do all the backing up here...
# ... and run the backup_command as user "otheruser":
sudo -u noslenkwah /path/to/backup_command --with --some --options

# Start myservice
systemctl start myservice.service
```

### Another approach …

… would be to add the `systemctl` commands to a file in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory so that a specific user may run them without supplying a password.

1. issue `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/noslenkwah`
     (The filename, `noslenkwah` doesn't matter, it is just a 
      personal habit of mine to name the files after the "main"
      user affected by the settings in that file. It just needs
      to be a file below the directory `/etc/sudoers.d`.)
2. Add the following lines and save the file.

   ```
   Cmnd_Alias MYSERVICE = \
       /bin/systemctl stop myservice.service, \
       /bin/systemctl start myservice.service

   noslenkwah ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: MYSERVICE
   ```

This allows the user `noslenkwah` to run `sudo systemctl stop myservice.service` and `sudo systemctl start myservice.service` without a password. It defines a socalled *command alias* (collection of commands) named `MYSERVICE` and then allows

- the user `noslenkwah`
- on `ALL` computers
- as user `root`
- without a password
- to run the commands defined by `MYSERVICE`

Replace `noslenkwah` and `myservice` with the actual username and service name. Note that you really must issue `sudo systemctl start myservice.service` for this to work (not `sudo systemctl start myservice` (without `.service`, for example).

Don't care about the *"on `ALL` computers"* part. This is relevant only if you intend to distribute the very same `sudoers` file to multiple computers.

You would then change your backup script to

```
# Stop myservice
sudo systemctl stop myservice.service

# Do all the backing up here...
/path/to/backup_command --with --some --options

# Start myservice
sudo systemctl start myservice.service
```

and have it run as user `noslenkwah`.

Answer (score 4):

Run this shell script as root.

For example, put it in the root crontab:
`sudo crontab -e`

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as sudo
Or, create a user without a home directory, add it to the sudoers file, give it special permissions to not require a password and run that script, as per PerlDuck's answer (item 2), and then run the command with

```
sudo -u <your_created_user>
```