# How to allow a command to be executed for a particular user without password with sudoers file?

Tags: permissions, sudo, visudo

Can anyone please explain the exact work of these in `/etc/sudoers` ? (I've done some research, so please don't share any links)

I want to add myself (member of `sudo`) to execute a command without password.But it's again asking for password.

```
# User

    root  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

    myself  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/apt update, PASSWD:/bin/apt install*

# Groups 

    %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 4):

I pretty much stole it from here: [Is it possible to give sudo access to only a particular command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90726/is-it-possible-to-give-sudo-access-to-only-a-particular-command)

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/Username
```

And add that to the file:

```
Username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt* update
Username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt* install
```

Don't know how to make this a one-liner, though. Hope that helps.

Comment: It can be made a one-liner with a command alias `Cmnd_Alias`, see the sudoers snippet in [this loosely related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103665/504066), section _Another approach_.

Answer (score 3):

The order of configuration lines has significance in the sudoers file: the **last** applicable line wins.

If user `myself` is a member of the `sudo` group, all commands issued by that user will always match the `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` line. As it has no `NOPASSWD:` flag, password will be asked.

The fix is to arrange the `/etc/sudoers` configuration lines in the order of increasing specificity:

```
# Groups 

    %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# User

    root  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

    myself  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/apt update, PASSWD:/bin/apt install*
```

When this order is used, if user `myself` runs `sudo apt update`, it will match the last line with the `NOPASSWD:` flag.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first post on askubuntu but i am pretty sure you could do it like that create a file with your `username` in `/etc/sudoers.d/` with:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: `NOPASSWD: ALL` is aimed at making all commands run without passwords. So `ALL` should be replaced by  `/bin/apt update`.  But overall you're right, I think.  This syntax should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add the next line to your sudoers file:

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: command1, command2, command3 [...]
```

Remember to separated with commas all commands you want to be executed by user with out password promp.