# How to allow a user to start/stop a specific system service?

Tags: permissions, systemd, users, services

I am building a server on which my students will be able to upload their projects, which are Python+Flask web-applications. When I add a new user, I add a new service in `/etc/systemd/system/[username].service`, that automatically runs the user app.

I would like to allow each user to start, stop and restart his/her own service, but not the services of others. So Alice would be able to do e.g. `service Alice restart` and Bob will be able to do `service Bob restart`, but not vice-versa.

is this possible?

Comment: Can you set up a user service instead? Those are inherently per-user, so the users wouldn't need additional permissions to control them.

Comment: @muru but a user service stops when the user disconnects. I want the web-apps to remain active even after the users leave.

Comment: Not if you enable lingering: `sudo loginctl enable-linger <username>`

Comment: @muru I read that linger consumes a lot of resources, since it keeps the entire user session active after the user disconnects. All I need is a way for a user to run a specific privileged command, without access to other privileged commands.

Comment: The entire user session that's kept alive is essentially just those user services which are enabled for those user. If this is on a server, which I guess it is, then it's just this service which you're making, because the other usual user services are desktop ones like pulseaudio.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with a workaround like this:

1. Create a Bash script (executable) under `/usr/local/bin` for each user (called `<user>.sh` for example's sake).
2. The script for each user just runs the command to restart that user's service, e.g.: `systemctl restart <user>` 
    *(If you're creative, you could add different functionality to this script to both start, stop and restart said service.)*
3. Add to the `sudoers` file the ability for each user to run only their own script. This is done [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108782/how-to-allow-a-command-to-be-executed-for-a-particular-user-without-password-wit) (under the `# User` section):

   ```
   # User
   <user> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/<user>.sh
   ```

Now each user can run their own `/usr/local/bin/<user>.sh` without typing a password, and this will restart their service (or do whatever you allow the script to do).

Comment: There's no reason for having the NOPASSWD, it shouldn't be a problem for the students to have to enter their password for a sudo command.

Comment: You're right, that's completely optional. ^^

Comment: Do I need to add a separate line for each user? Maybe there is a way to add a generic line that allows each "user" to run "/usr/local/bin/user.sh"?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi that depends on how you design your script - but as a basis yes. However, it should be possible to do a clever solution with only one script, but that would take some more work (since it then needs info about who ran the script).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible currently to do on a per-unit basis, but will hopefully become possible soon when https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit/-/merge_requests/154 is merged and available in a release